# Get base class from inheriting class

Tags: c#, reflection

I would like to get the base class from

```
public class Class1 : BrowserWindow
```

I am trying to "convert" `Class1` into `UiBrowserWindow` via a method in `UiBrowserWindow`. Something like this...

```
public class UiBrowserWindow : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow {
    public static UiBrowserWindow Convert(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow browserWindow) {
        UiBrowserWindow result = new UiBrowserWindow();
        result = (UiBrowserWindow)browserWindow;
        return result;
    }
}

UiBrowserWindow browserWindow = UiBrowserWindow.Convert(UIMap.Class1.GetType().BaseType);
//UIMap.Class1 is a property of UIMap
```

This code produces the error `Argument type 'System.Type' is not assignable to parameter type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow'`

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
public class UiBrowserWindow : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow {
    public static UiBrowserWindow convert(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow browserWindow) {
        UiBrowserWindow result = (UiBrowserWindow)browserWindow;
        return result;
    }
}

// Usage...
UiBrowserWindow browserWindow = UiBrowserWindow.convert(UIMap.Class1);
```

This is causing an exception `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'automatedTesting.Class1' to type 'UiBrowserWindow'`

TestMethod...

```
[TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod1() {
    this.UIMap.RecordedMethod1();

    UiBrowserWindow browserWindow = UiBrowserWindow.convert(UIMap.Class1);
    Assert.IsNotNull(browserWindow.getUiTestControl<HtmlDiv>(new[] { 
        new PropertyExpression(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id, "logo")
    }));
}
```

Comment: Don't use reflection. See Novakov's answer: An object of type `Class1` is always "assignable to" the type `BrowserWindow`. That's what inheritance (base classes) is all about. Also: In your `Convert` method, don't assign `result` to a `new UiBrowserWindow` that you are not going to use anyway. Simply remove that `new` expression.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you should omit ".GetType().BaseType" part and call:

```
UiBrowserWindow browserWindow = UiBrowserWindow.Convert(UIMap.Class1);
```

Update:
Class1 derives from BrowserWindow, UiBrowserWindow derives from BrowserWindow. Class1 is NOT UiBrowserWindow. The conversion you're trying will work only with overload cast operator (but I don't recommend it). Explain what you're trying to achive because this way will not work

Comment: This is causing an exception `InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'automatedTesting.Class1' to type 'UiBrowserWindow'`

Comment: `Class1` is a class that is auto generated by the Coded UI Test Builder in VS2010. We already have a framework built out to create coded ui tests through code. What I'm trying to do is allow a user to record a TestMethod and then write their own asserts using our framework, but in order to do that the auto generated `BrowserWindow` wrapper class (in this case `Class1`) needs to be converted into our wrapper class, `UiBrowserWindow`. I'll add the TestMethod above for clarification

Comment: Like `UiBrowserWindow`, `Class1` gives you a handle to the browser.